# How Replicate database between server and client and know if two database have same data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-replication

i'm developing a project what I have a central database with data that is updated frecuently, there are clients who have a instance of the central database(The same schema and tables), that clients need to know in some moment if there are changes in the central database to update their client database.

Im working on MySql (5.4), I like to know two things:
1-) Is there a way to know the central database state (If changes has been made to the data or the data has not changed)?
2-) Is there a way to update my client database from the central database to have the replication of the central database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports replication. [FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-replication.html)

You're almost certainly better off letting MySQL do this instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: That being said, it may not be applicable here — MySQL replication is based on a single master database sending updates to replicas. It is **not** a synchronization system.

Comment: I know. I think almost everything the OP needs to know is in the FAQ.

Comment: Ok thanks for the FAQ,I didn't know how the replication system works, I was expecting a syncronization system but it notifies constantly changes in all slaves its better than I was expecting